# Linux fortune program source code

Tags: linux, command, open-source

I am using fortune command in my shell script. I want to embed these quotations in web based program.
Where I can find source code and quotation database of fortune command in Linux distribution?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the source code and database for the Debian version are maintained here:
http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/fortune-mod.git

(I found this via the Debian package tracking system for the fortunes package:
https://packages.qa.debian.org/f/fortune-mod.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help] - instead of answering, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

For just the quotation database on a Debian based distro go to `/usr/share/games/fortunes`. Quotes are there just in plain text. You can add there some other databases, search with:

```
apt search ^fortunes
```